# How to include new php file/class in yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i want to include pagination ajax class to yii2.
how can i do that?
when i use below code :

```html
<?
 $url = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/Pagination.php';
include $url;

?>
```

in controller and also below code:

```html
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '\..\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Extensions\Pagination.php';
```

but both of them shows below error:

Call to undefined method Yii::app()

how can i fix it?
is it true way to save pagination.php?
please help me to include this file to my yii2 project..

thannks all :)

Comment: `Yii::$app->basePath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong access to yii2  components

In yii2 you should use  $app

```
Yii::$app->->basePath
```

and not `Yii::app()`

Comment: can you please tell me how to set stream ?because is fail to open stream .

is it true way??

Comment: i don't know  ... why you are using  require_once  for extension .. normally the extension are installed  by composer and  loaded by autoload ..   ..

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Setting unknown property: yii\data\Pagination::baseURL.it shows this.whats wrong?

Comment: try take a look at how use phpunit in yii2  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-unit.html